# Potential energy of molecule

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry

Does potential energy of molecule and therefore bond length change with temperature?

Comment: Please don't repost variants of your question.

Comment: Going by standard terminology, potential energy surface of an isolated molecule is defined within adiabatic approximation by solving for eigenvalues of molecular Hamiltonian (minus Kinetic energy operator of nuclei). This way you get infinite number of potential energy surfaces corresponding roughly to potential experienced by nuclei given a particular electronic adiabatic state (excluding non adiabatic coupling terms). So appriori there is no information of temperature. Bond lengths are defined as inter-molecular distances where force is zero (Equilibrium positions).

Comment: But you can define thermal averaged bond lengths as those which minimize free energies. All this is valid given molecules are isolated.